# CodecConfigurationException when using bulk write API

Tags: mongodb, bulkupdate

I'm using mongodb's bulk write api to update/upsert several documents at once in an unordered fashion. I use the response to monitor number of upserts, updates, deletes, etc. Once in a while my code throws the [CodecConfigurationException](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/org/bson/codecs/configuration/CodecConfigurationException.html) because it can't update fields such as BigInteger.

1. When such an exception is thrown do other commands go through successfully? From what I can tell, it does seem so
2. If other updates are being applied successfully then shouldn't such an error be part of the [MongoBulkWriteException](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoBulkWriteException.html) that allows for successful writes to be monitored and pin-points the unsuccessful writes along with the reason for write failure. How can one determine the failed update if we're updating, say 50000 documents at a time?
3. If no updates go through then is it that this exception is triggered even before the command is executed on the server side? Is this is a purely client side exception?